# A way to declare a NDEF_DISCOVERED IntentFilter attribute in MonoDroid?

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, nfc

I am new to Monodroid and was wondering if there is a way to use an `IntentFilter` attribute to declare this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

I tried looking for it using Visual Studio's intellisense but nothing shows up. I already included Android.Nfc.

The reason for this is because I'm having trouble getting my app to run properly. It always says "Unfortunately, app_name has stopped". I don't know if it's an `AndroidManifest.xml` merging problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`IntentFilterAttribute`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.App.IntentFilterAttribute#) to generate that:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" }, 
              Categories = new[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"}, 
              DataMimeType = "text/plain")]
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could do that. Will try this now. :)